# How to get a UIView current position?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a UIView appearing when the user taps the screen.
After that, the UIView is dropping due to gravity by UIGravityBehavior.

Is there a way to get the UIView's position while dropping?

```
- (IBAction)makePoint:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin = [sender locationInView:self.gameView];
    frame.size = pointSize; //pre-defined size..

    _point = [[myPoint alloc]initWithFrame:frame]; //This is UIView

    [self.gameView addSubview:_point];
    [self.gravity addItem:_point];
    [self.collider addItem:_point];
}
```

I'm trying to get the CGPoint of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use action block on the UIGravityBehavior like this,

```
gravityBehavior.action = ^{
   CGRect frame = gravityView.frame;
   CGRect otherViewFrame = otherView.frame;
   if(CGRectIntersects(frame, otherViewFrame)){
     // put your custom logic here 
   }
};
```

I hope that helps.

Look this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicBehavior_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDynamicBehavior/action#jumpTo_3 for further detail.

Comment: The only problem is that your code is generating memory leak for me because my gravityView is strong.. I fixed it by this: __weak yourViewController *selfie = self; and then in the block replaced gravityView,frame with selfie,gravityView.frame.

Comment: I typed it out of mind. So there could be come mistake. Glad I could help :)